# How to return a value from a then() block and use it in another then block in cypress

Tags: automated-testing, cypress

```js
  cy.get('div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-item.MuiGrid-grid-xs-6 > div > span.MuiChip-label').then(($today) => {
    
    const today=$today.text()
    cy.log("today")
    cy.log(today.charAt(0))
  })

  cy.get('div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-item.MuiGrid-grid-xs-6 > div > span.MuiChip-label').then(($tomorrow,today) => {
    const tom=$tomorrow.text()
    cy.log("tomorrow")
    cy.log(tom.charAt(0))
  })
```

I want to add `today.charAt(0)` and `tom.CharAt(0)`, how can I do this in second `then` block?

Comment: The various options are all covered in https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases

Comment: That fixed my issue, thanks a lot.

Comment: Just note that this question is about Javascript's closures. It is better asked in Stack Overflow rather than SQA Stack Exchange.

Comment: Can a value be returned from then to be used by another function.

Answer (score 3):

It's mentioned in the documentation mentioned in the comment section, I recommend reading it.
Specifically, you can read this part about [closures](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Closures).

What you can do is to put the other `cy.get()` inside the first one:

```js
cy
  .get('...')
  .then($today => {
    
    cy
      .get('...')
      .then($tomorrow => {
        // you have access to both $today and $tomorrow
    });
});
```

I shortened the code (e.g. didn't use the long selectors) in order to focus on the main point.